# What does "Essential Travels" mean?

Tags: meaning

I live in Israel, and at the 12th of August I need to travel to some place in Russia.

My travel goes through Turkey, as the place I am traveling to costs more and takes longer if I travel through Moscow.

Now Israel is at war, and Turkey goes against Israel and the news says:

> Please avoid non-essential traveling to Turkey

What does that mean?

Real message translation:

> Warning: Avoid non-essential travel to Turkey
>
> The face of violent protests in Turkey against Israeli Foreign Ministry called avoid unnecessary visits and take precautions. Diplomats were evacuated close

Comment: Welcome to the site! Was this message originally in Hebrew? If so, does it make sense to try and interpret the translation?

Comment: @Cerberus I don't really know hebrew that well, thats why I translated it to english

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a message written in Hebrew, translated by the OP, that we are supposed to interpret.

Comment: This is not about English, you could ask on [travel.se] instead. However, these are just political considerations really and they don't apply to when you just pass through a country in transit to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above passage, *non-essential travel* means-

- Non necessary trip

OR

- Non urgent trip

So basically the government is announcing that you must avoid that route unless completely *necessary* or *urgent*.